# Pass ng-model as parameter to function

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, reusability

Hi I am new at angular and I want to be reuse a function to modify different models.

```
 <p ng-bind="f1" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f2" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f3" ></p>
 <button  ng-click="write()" >Save</button>
```

For instance i have the above html. I want to be able to use `write()` to bind data for f1,f2 or f3 depending on which one i pass to write(). How do i inform write of the model to bind data to? In other words how do i make the function reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in order to have access to specific models in my function

```
 <p ng-bind="f1" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f2" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f3" ></p>
 <button  ng-click="write("f1")" >Save</button>
```

I passed the model as a string and in my function

```
$scope.write= function(modelName){
$scope[modelName] = "Some Value"
}
```

This way write() can be used by any model

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the ng-model to the function,

```
<button  ng-click="write(f1)" >Save</button>
```

and in cotroller,

```
$scope.write = function(val){
 //do with the value
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I dont need the value I need the reference to the  model  so i can do `$scope.val = "something"` instead of `$scope.f1 = "something"`. I dont want to have 3 different write functions

Comment: @flexxxit Still i dont understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.write = function(val){
 if(val.f1){
//do watevr u want
}
else if(val.f2){
//if value f2 is not undefined
}
else if(val.f3){

}




<p data-ng-model="obejct.f1" ></p><p data-ng-model="obejct.f2" ></p><p data-ng-model="obejct.f3" ></p><button  data-ng-click="write(object)" >Save</button>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this

**> js:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.f1 = 'Welcome';
  $scope.f2 = 'to';
  $scope.f3 = 'Bangladesh';
  $scope.write = function(x,y,z){
    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
    console.log(z)
    $scope[x] = 52464645;
    console.log($scope[x]);
  };
});
```

> **html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="f1" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f2" ></p>
 <p ng-bind="f3" ></p>
 <button  ng-click="write(f1,f2,f3)" >Save</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

example. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/drZG4ZWetxOWPSPbxn26